# jquery .on() method with load event

Tags: jquery, events

How can we use jQuery .`on()` method with `load` event?  e.g. The code is:

```
<a href="#" id="add">Add</a>
<div id="initial">
     <input type="text" class="abc" name="in">
</div>
```

And the jQuery for it:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var x=$('#initial').html();
    $('#add').click(function(){
        $('body').append(x);
    });
    $(document).on('load','.abc',function(){
        alert('started');
    });
});
```

Comment: and whats the question/ prob ?

Comment: I think the user may be asking this question where in his actual project the element `.abc` is dynamically created by external library. i.e. he has no control when the element `.abc` is appended to the DOM.

Comment: @Anand Mohan Sinha: This is where you went wrong --> $(document).on('load', '.abc', handler).  Your selected answer is *entirely* about the .click() handler?  How could you have accepted it as correct?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Refer to http://api.jquery.com/on/

It says

> In all browsers, the load, scroll, and error events (e.g., on an `<img>`
>   element) do not bubble. In Internet Explorer 8 and lower, the paste
>   and reset events do not bubble. Such events are not supported for use
>   with delegation, but they can be used when the event handler is
>   directly attached to the element generating the event.

If you want to do something when a new input box is added then you can simply write the code after appending it.

```
$('#add').click(function(){
        $('body').append(x);
        // Your code can be here
    });
```

And if you want the same code execute when the first input box within the document is loaded  then you can write a function and call it in both places i.e. `$('#add').click` and document's ready event

Comment: It is a nice piece of info, but unfortunately irrelevant, imho.

Comment: How is this irrelevant? If the load event doesn't bubble up to the document level, this pretty much explains why you can't do a $(document).on("load", ".something", ...). On the contrary this is a pretty damn relevant answer.

Answer (score 14):

To run function onLoad

```
jQuery(window).on("load", function(){
    ..code..
});
```

To run code onDOMContentLoaded (also called onready)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    ..code..
});
```

or the recommended shorthand for onready

```
jQuery(function($){
    ..code.. ($ is the jQuery object)
});
```

onready fires when the document has loaded

onload fires when the document and all the associated content, like the images on the page have loaded.

Answer (score 11):

I'm not sure what you're going for here--by the time `jQuery(document).ready()` has executed, it has already loaded, and thus `document`'s load event will already have been called. Attaching the `load` event handler at this point will have no effect and it will never be called. If you're attempting to `alert` "started" once the document has loaded, just put it right in the `(document).ready()` call, like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var x = $('#initial').html();
    $('#add').click(function() {
        $('body').append(x);
    });
    
    alert('started');
    
});​
```

If, as your code also appears to insinuate, you want to fire the alert when `.abc` has loaded, put it in an individual `.load` handler:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var x = $('#initial').html();
    $('#add').click(function() {
        $('body').append(x);
    });
    
    $(".abc").on("load", function() {
        alert('started');
    })
});​
```

Finally, I see little point in using `jQuery` in one place and `$` in another. It's generally better to keep your code consistent, and either use `jQuery` everywhere or `$` everywhere, as the two are generally interchangeable.

Comment: @Jashwant: Exactly. If `ready` has executed before the `load` event, attaching the `load` event to the document once `ready` has fired would be redundant.

Comment: @Imdad - jQuery 1.8 docs: ".load(handler(eventObject)) ... is a shortcut for .on('load', handler)." available from: August 2012, betas from June and I think under 1.7 it was available, so you can upvote

Answer (score 0):

As the other have mentioned, the load event does not bubble. Instead you can  manually trigger a load-like event with a custom event:

```
$('#item').on('namespace/onload', handleOnload).trigger('namespace/onload')
```

If your element is already listening to a `change` event:

```
$('#item').on('change', handleChange).trigger('change')
```

I find this works well. Though, I stick to custom events to be more explicit and avoid side effects.

Answer (score 0):

One could just do something like:

```
jQuery(document).on('change', '#my_id', function() {
    // Your code can be here
})

jQuery('#my_id').change();
```

For your case

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var x=$('#initial').html();
    $('#add').click(function(){
        $('body').append(x);
    });

    $(document).on('change','.abc',function(){
        alert('started');
    // Your code can be here
    });

    $('.abc').change();
});
```