# Run jquery Once content of a div has fully loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div `am-events-booking` that is dynamically loaded using Javascript and this div normally takes a second or so to load after the page has loaded. I would like to run a jQuery code once the contents of this div has fully loaded.

Below is the workaround i have used to delay the running of the script by 5000ms however this doesn't seem to be correct as if the page load takes more than 5000ms then the script would not run. Is there are better way to do this? May be use mutations and if so, how do I go about it?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var i = setInterval(function() {
      if ($("#am-events-booking").text().length > 0) {
        clearInterval(i);

        $(".am-event-data").addClass('bg');

      } else {
        console.log("Waiting...");
      }
    }, 5000);
    console.log("Page is loaded");
  });
});
```

```css
.am-event-data {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 50%;
}

.bg {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="am-events-booking">


  <div class="am-event-data">
    <div class="am-event-date">
      <div class="am-event-date-month" style="color: rgb(249, 169, 126);">Mar</div>
      <div class="am-event-date-day">24</div>

    </div>
    <div class="am-event-info">
      <div class="am-event-title">Ballet
        <span class="am-event-booking-status open">Open</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="am-event-data">
    <div class="am-event-date">
      <div class="am-event-date-month" style="color: rgb(249, 169, 126);">April</div>
      <div class="am-event-date-day">25</div>

    </div>
    <div class="am-event-info">
      <div class="am-event-title">Other
        <span class="am-event-booking-status open">Open</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Surely the code that dynamically loads the content provides a way to perform actions when the loading has completed.

Comment: Look into [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/MutationObserver) if not.

Comment: @Pointy dont have access to change the code that load dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you taken a look at jQuery .on('load')?

The following answer may help - https://stackoverflow.com/a/58871367/3907839

Alternatively, can you use something like this?

https://gist.github.com/chrisjhoughton/7890303#file-wait-el-js

So in your case, include the waitForEl function in your code and then use it. Take a read through the comments for relevant refactored code, I've just looked at the first bit.

```
waitForEl($("#am-events-booking"), function() {
    $(".am-event-data").addClass('bg');
});
```

Comment: @how would i incorporate this onto my code?

Comment: @user38208 I have edited the response with another option to review.

Comment: This link actually worked 

https://gist.github.com/chrisjhoughton/7890303#file-wait-el-js